# Lodash: is it possible to use map with async functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await, lodash

Consider this code

```
const response  = await fetch('<my url>');
const responseJson = await response.json();
responseJson =  _.sortBy(responseJson, "number");

responseJson[0] = await addEnabledProperty(responseJson[0]);
```

*What `addEnabledProperty` does is to extend the object adding an `enabled` property, but this is not important. The function itself works well*

```
async function addEnabledProperty (channel){

    const channelId = channel.id;
    const stored_status = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`ChannelIsEnabled:${channelId}`);
    let boolean_status = false;
    if (stored_status == null) {
        boolean_status = true;
    } else {
        boolean_status = (stored_status == 'true');
    }

    return _.extend({}, channel, { enabled: boolean_status });
}
```

**Is there a way to use `_.map` (or another system), to loop trough entire responseJson array to use `addEnabledProperty` against each element?**

I tried:

```
responseJson = _.map(responseJson,  function(channel) {
            return addEnabledProperty(channell);
        });
```

But it's not using async so it freeze the app.

I tried:

```
responseJson = _.map(responseJson,  function(channel) {
            return await addEnabledProperty(chanell);
        });
```

But i got a js error (about the row `return await addEnabledProperty(chanell);`)

> await is a reserved word

Then tried

```
responseJson = _.map(responseJson, async function(channel) {
            return await addEnabledProperty(channell);
        });
```

But I got an array of Promises... and I don't understand why...

What else!??

**EDIT**: I understand your complains about I didn't specify that `addEnabledProperty()` returns a `Promise`, but, really, I didn't know it. In fact, I wrote  "*I got an array of Promises... and I don't understand why* "

Comment: *"But I got an array of Promises... and I don't understand why..."* Because an `async` function returns a promise and `.map` creates an array of the values returned by the callback. `Promise.all` is the way to "resolve" an array of promises.

Comment: Per your third example, any `async` function always returns a promise, which is why you get an array of them. But, you can try: `responseJson = await Promise.all(_.map(responseJson, function(channel) { return addEnabledProperty(channel) }))`

Comment: `await is a reserved word` where did you get this error?

Comment: Does `addEnabledProperty` return a `Promise`?

Comment: @guest271314 I hope so, since OP is `await`ing it in his first snippet. EDIT: I should note that awaiting a non-promise is still valid, so perhaps it doesn't?.

Comment: @CRice OP does not mention at text of Question that `addEnabledProperty()` returns a `Promise` _"What `addEnabledProperty` does is to extend the object adding an `enabled` property, but this is not important. The function itself works well"_

Comment: @guest271314 Indeed. Although awaiting a function that doesn't return a promise is pointless, it is still valid JS, so you may be right. I'm just hoping that OP would not await something that's not a promise.

Comment: I understand your complains about I didn't specify that `addEnabledProperty()` returns a `Promise`, but, really, I didn't know it. In fact, I wrote  "_I got an array of Promises... and I don't understand why_ "

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To process your response jsons in parallel you may use `Promise.all`:

```
const responseJson = await response.json();
responseJson = _.sortBy(responseJson, "number");

let result = await Promise.all(_.map(responseJson, async (json) => 
  await addEnabledProperty(json))
);
```

---

Since `addEnabledProperty` method is async, the following also should work (per @CRice):

```
let result = await Promise.all(_.map(responseJson, addEnabledProperty));
```

Comment: No need for the `async` anonymous function. `(json) => addEnabledProperty(json)` is functionally identical. Also, afaik, we can just pass that function to the map directly, without the wrapper: `_.map(responseJson, addEnabledProperty)`

Comment: @CRice _"No need for the async anonymous function."_ If OP is expecting a `Promise` to be returned and `await` to be used, `await` would cause error if `async` is not used at anonymous arrow function

Comment: This works, and you made me understand that a using `await` make a function to return a `promise` !

Comment: @Crice can you explain why it still works when `async await` are omitted on `addEnabledProperty`?

Comment: @Saitama it works because you are wrapping a function that returns a Promise (and we know because you need to use 'await') with another function which still returns a Promise. And since the only argument of the anonymous async arrow is passed down to 'addEnabledProperty' we can therefore be pretty sure you *don’t* need to wrap it. It would be necessary if 'addEnabledProperty' accepted a second (or third) argument that we do not want to pollute with what is passed from `_.map`.

Answer (score 4):

I found that I didn't have to put the async / await inside of the `Promise.all` wrapper.

Using that knowledge, in conjunction with lodash chain (`_.chain`) could result in the following simplified version of the accepted answer:

```
const responseJson = await Promise.all( _
                       .chain( response.json() )
                       .sortBy( 'number' )
                       .map( json => addEnabledProperty( json ) )
                       .value()
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()` to run all the promises in your array.

```
responseJson = await Promise.all(_.map(responseJson, (channel) => {
        return addEnabledProperty(channel);
    }));
```

Comment: There is no need to declare this async and await the `addEnabledProperty`.  Using `function(channel) { return addEnabledProperty(channel) }` would achieve the same result. For even further simplification: `_.map(responseJson, addEnabledProperty)` to avoid the needless wrapper function.

Comment: @Crice can you explain WHY it is not needed?

Comment: It's not needed because all that an async function does is return a promise. You can skip that and simply return the `addEnabledProperty` promise directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about using partial.js(https://github.com/marpple/partial.js)

It cover both promise and normal pattern by same code.

```
_p.map([1, 2, 3], async (v) => await promiseFunction());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate over some object, you can use `keys` first to get an array of keys and then just loop over your keys while awaiting for necessary actions.

This works when you want to wait until every previous iteration step is finished before getting into the next one.

Here is a consolidated `asyncMap` function that you can use for your object:

```
async function asyncMap(obj, cb) {
  const result = {};

  const keysArr = keys(obj);

  let keysArrLength = keysArr.length;
  while (keysArrLength-- > 0) {
    const key = keysArr[keysArrLength];

    const item = obj[key];

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    result[key] = await cb(item, key);
  }

  return result;
}
```

And then, for your example case:

```
responseJson = await asyncMap(responseJson, addEnabledProperty);
```

Otherwise use `Promise.all` like was proposed above to run all the iteration steps in parallel