# How to use async await inside Lodash _.times function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, lodash

I would like to invoke an asynchronous function n times, invoking each time only after the previous one has resolved.

This is the code that works:

```
async startGame() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.totalNumberOfSets; i++) {
  await this.startSet();
  }
}
```

I would like to convert it to the Lodash function `_.times`.

I tried using this answer: [Lodash: is it possible to use map with async functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065444/lodash-is-it-possible-to-use-map-with-async-functions)

this way:

```
async startGame() {
  await Promise.all(_.times(this.totalNumberOfSets, async () => {
    await this.startSet()
  }))
};
```

but all the function invoked immediately four times without waiting to resolve.

Also tried this:

```
  async startGame() {
   let resArray = [];
   await Promise.all(_.times(this.totalNumberOfSets, async () =>{
     let res = await this.startSet()
     resArray.push(res);
    }
  ))
 };
```

but it didn't work as expected as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to synchronize a sequence of promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package, which supports async/await in lodash
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-dash